# Any SoSAssist equivalent free tool for debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, sos

I had used SosAssistin past and it was awesome, now I i tried to download it again but it is no longer available :( any other tool which can visually show memory/threads/callstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the helpful [.cmdtree](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104011015/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/09/17/special-command-execute-commands-from-a-customized-user-interface-with-cmdtree.aspx) command in WinDbg to display a tree view that contains a list of commands to use in your debugging scenarios (you could customize it according to your personal needs).

[Sample config](https://web.archive.org/web/20110710044856/http://www.wintellect.com:80/CS/files/folders/7040/download.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this which is in Beta (I'm the Developer)
http://www.debuganalyzer.net

Visualizer is not completed yet but coming sooooon...